# Entity Framework - nested entites are null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have one-to-many relationship, which I designed using [this.](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)
and I use Code-First approach.

i.e.:

```
public class JobData
{
    [Key]
    public int JobDataId { get; set; }
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<TaskInfo> TaskInfoes { get; set; }
}
```

Where `TaskInfo` is defined like this:

```
public class TaskInfo
{
    public int TaskInfoId { get; set; }
    public int ExecId { get; set; }

    public virtual FrameData FrameData { get; set; }
    public virtual Card Card { get; set; }
    public virtual Tags Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual DriverInfo DriverInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual JobData JobData { get; set; }
}
```

FrameData, Card, Tags, DriverInfo are all one-to-one entites with TaskInfo:

```
public class DriverInfo
{       
    public int DriverId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TaskInfo")]
    public int DriverInfoId { get; set; }
    public virtual TaskInfo TaskInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Tables are created just fine with this approach, I get JobData table and TaskInfoes table, that hold reference to JobData and I also have tables for each nested class in TaskInfo. The data is even saved correctly, thus, every table is populated. However, when I'm trying to get jobData instance, it has entire list of TaskInfoes, but all nested classes are unfortunately null. 
What am i doing wrong here? 
I have been trying different solutions, like specifying `[Key,ForeignKey("")` in nested classes, tried creating separate context for TaskInfoes and use something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TaskInfo>()               
            .HasRequired<JobData>(s => s.JobData) // TaskInfo entity requires JobData 
            .WithMany(s => s.TaskInfoes)        // JobData entity includes many TaskInfoes entities
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

modelBuilder.Entity<TaskInfo>()
            .HasRequired<FrameData>(s => s.FrameData);// TaskInfo entity requires FrameData
```

As well as:

```
var data = context.TaskInfoes
        .Include(s => s.Framedata)
        .Include(s => s.Card)
        .Include(s => s.DriverInfo)
        .Include(s => s.Tags)
        .ToList();
```

Nothing works, nested classes are null no matter what. I'm totally missing something important here, could you please tell me what ? :)

P.S. the way I am getting jobData instance is either

```
 return context.Jobs.Find(id);
```

or

```
return context.Jobs.SingleOrDefault(job => job.JobId == id);
```

Comment: Looks like improper `one-to-one` configuration. Are you mapping to exiting database or it has been generated by Code First migration from the above model? Can we see for instance the `DriverInfo` **table**?

Comment: hmm, I was thinking about this, indeed, nested class tables do not have any keys..why? here is the [table](https://yadi.sk/i/RmZKncZm3Lup3s)
P.S. I was using "Configure one-to-zero-or-one relationship using DataAnnotations:" from [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Where is `TaskInfo.JobData` in code?

Comment: Well, configuring one-to-one FK relationship is not so easy due to limited EF support (EF uses by default and supports much better [Shared Primary Key Associations](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations))

Comment: @grek40 , missed it, TaskInfo has `public virtual JobData JobData { get; set; }`

Comment: Could it be an issue, that I'm trying to make multiple one-to-one relationships? Doesn't look to be a common case in EF

Comment: Could you show the database diagram of those tables?

Comment: @Amarula multiple 1:0..1 relations should not be a problem by themself, but as Win said, a database diagram might help at this point, because the 1:0..1 relation might become a problem when there are (for example) multiple 1:many relations that reference some of the 1:0..1 relation objects.

Answer (score 0):

> FrameData, Card, Tags, DriverInfo are all one-to-one entites with TaskInfo:

You don't need to reference for example TaskInfo as having a DriverInfo object and the DriverInfo object with the TaskInfo object. Just have one object referencing the other object.

TaskInfo has FKs which are PKs of the other objects FrameData, Card, Tags, DriverInfo.

```
public class TaskInfo
{
    public int TaskInfoId { get; set; }
    public int ExecId { get; set; }
    .../...
    public int DriverInfoId  { get; set; } // The PK of DriverInfo
    public virtual DriverInfo DriverInfo { get; set; }

}
```

Remove reference to TaskInfo.

```
public class DriverInfo
{       
    public int DriverId { get; set; }
    public int DriverInfoId { get; set; }
}
```

It would be better to use FirstOrdefault as it will handle a null return.

```
return context.Jobs.FirstOrDefault(job => job.JobId == id);
```

Comment: that was just a no brainer after 8 hours wasted to make the thing work. I'm going to try your solution.

Comment: I think the beginning of part **2.** is wrong. `ForeignKey` does not determine the key property name of a referenced object but it relates a navigation property name to a key property name within the same class.

Comment: @grek40 is right, I'm getting this error: 
The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'TaskInfoIdFK' on type '*.FrameData' is not valid. The navigation property 'TaskInfoId' was not found on the dependent type '*FrameData'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

btw, if I remove references of DriverInfo,Card,etc. in TaskInfo class, how would I access them afterwards? I mean that TaskInfo would not have any references to these classes.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Tried this approach, and I'm getting "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entitySet" error, decided to isolate it, and if I set `[NotMapped]` attribute to my nested classes , it works just fine..perhaps, we are missing something else here?

Comment: @Amarula are you using the term "nested classes" the way it is meant to be used in C#? Because you shouldn't use nested classes for EF entity classes.

Comment: @YvetteColomb
code-first, I've made changes according to your edited answer. Looks like [this](https://yadi.sk/d/GYDMNiLI3LyLy4)
and I am using Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -Force to recreate configuration files